# Checking Differentiability for given function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Find if the function $x\mapsto |\sin (x)-1|$ is differentiable at  $x=\pi /2$ .

I get stuck at $$\lim_{h \rightarrow 0}{ \left|{\cos h \over h}\right|}$$

Comment: We're talking $\mathbb{R}$ here, aren't we? Write $\lvert\sin x - 1\rvert$ in a way that doesn't use an absolute value.

Comment: How did you get $\cos h/h$?

Comment: To add to @DanielFischer's comment, many times the difficulty with absolute value problems comes from a basic inability to translate the symbols into their definitions.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 Hey, do you have some link that can help me understand it better ?

Comment: Aman, maybe [this M.SE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/what-is-the-best-way-to-solve-an-equation-involving-multiple-absolute-values) would be a good starting point...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

With Graham Hesketh's solution, the differentiability of $(1-\sin x)$ is established here

As $$\frac{d f(x)}{dx}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$$

$$\implies \frac{d f(x)}{dx}_{(\text{at }x=a)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}h$$

Here $f(x)=1-\sin x, a=\frac\pi2$

So,
$$\frac{d(1-\sin x)}{dx}_{(\text{at }x=\frac\pi2)}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-\sin (\frac\pi2+h)-(1-\sin\frac\pi2) }h=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{1-\cos h}h$$ which is proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437526/how-to-find-the-limits-lim-limits-h-rightarrow-0-frace-h-h-and-li)

Comment: Thanks Again, 1 side question though, if i just have to find the limit of $cosh \over h$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ how do i approach it ?  The answer is "doesn;t exist" right ?

Comment: @AmanMittal, my pleasure. As $\cos 0=1, \lim_{h\to0^+}\frac{\cos h}h=+\infty, \lim_{h\to0^-}\frac{\cos h}h=-\infty$

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(x)\le 1\Rightarrow |\sin(x)-1|=1-\sin(x)$

so this example is differentiable everywhere.

[see lab bhattacharjee's solution for the differentiability of $1-\sin(x)$   ]

:)